# RavenDB Receiving not supported exception: Expression type not supported when using where query

Tags: linq, ravendb

I'm running the following query to try and find all relevant notifications to display to a user. However, Raven is not happy about something somewhere in the query. I've determined that the last 2 lines involving the date are fine, but the rest isn't (any of them seem to upset it). The only useful bit of information I'm getting is that it is "Expression type not supported: System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression". None of these look unusually typed for LINQ.

One thing to mention is that action is an instance of an enum, with n.Actions being a list of them. Similarly with user.HiddenNotificationTypes and n.Type. I'm not sure if that could be what is throwing it.

```
 /* Find all notifications that:
 * Have no actions associated or the action that the user has performed
 * There are no targets or the user is one of the targets
 * The user is not one of the users that has seen this notification
 * The notification type isn't one that the user has opted out of
 * The current DateTime is after the notification's start time
 * The current DateTime is before the expiry date of the notification
 * */
 notifications = session.Query<Notification>()
    .Where(n => (n.Actions == null || action.In(n.Actions))
        && (n.Targets.Count == 0 || user.Id.In(n.Targets))
        && (!user.Id.In(n.UsersSeen))
        && (!user.HiddenNotificationTypes.Contains(n.Type))
        && (n.StartDate == DateTime.MinValue || n.StartDate > DateTime.Now)
        && (n.ExpireDate == DateTime.MinValue || n.ExpireDate < DateTime.Now))
    .ToList();
```

Can anyone spot what might be causing this exception? Alternatively, if you think an index would work better for this query, what kind of index would I need?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: No, but it should be relatively easy to find by commenting out the where conditions and adding them back one at a time, until it blows up.

Comment: There's a lot of processing going on here. You'd be better off doing this in an index rather than a query

Comment: As for commenting the lines out one at a time, already done. Hence how I know it's unhappy with those clauses with the exception of the DateTime ones.

Comment: @levelnis, I've tried to see if I can solve this with an index. I've found myself virtually just having an index of the collection as it is, which I'm guessing isn't right. What kind of index did you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

This one: `user.HiddenNotificationTypes.Contains(n.Type)`

You should also avoid using DateTime.Now in queries, it prevents queries from being cached.

Comment: I took out that line but I'm still receiving the same exception. I take your point about using DateTime though because of Raven's love for precomputed queries, so I'll do those client side.

Comment: My next bet would be n.Targets.Count , although I'm pretty sure it should work. If that's not it, then I'd file a bug with RavenDB, it's probably the query expression tree is too big on the Linq provider